# Nodemcu littleFS

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I seem to be unable to read a file from the nodemcu(ESP 12-E module) after I have uploaded the file by using he tool ESP8266 LittleFS Data Upload in Arduino IDE. .

Running this sketch (named:Test_LittleFS):

```
#include "LittleFS.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if(!LittleFS.begin()){
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting LittleFS");
    return;
  }

 if(LittleFS.exists("/example.txt")) 
     {Serial.println("File does not exist");return;}
 else {Serial.println("File exists"); }

 File file = LittleFS.open("/example.txt", "r");
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;}

  Serial.println("File Content:");
  while(file.available()){
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }
 file.close();
}

void loop() {

}`
```

I do get the response "File exists" and "Failed to open file for reading".

The file example.txt is in the data folder which itself is in the sketch directory next to Test_littleFS.ino

BTW: I have experienced some trouble before getting LittleFS installed. It seems one should not use the most updated version of Arduino IDE. I am using 1.8.19:

Comment: Forget to mention that I am running Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a small mistake in your code, the line:

```
if(LittleFS.exists("/example.txt"))
  {Serial.println("File does not exist");return;}
```

it reads "if file exists" then print "File doesn't exist" :-)
it should be

```
if(!LittleFS.exists("/example.txt"))
```

notice the not exclamation mark "!"

That fixes the code logic which based on your explanation should now tell you that your LittleFS is mounted ok but the file doesn't exists.

Which, sadly doesn't solve the problem!

I use PlatformIO so I haven't used the Arduino IDE LittleFS tool but I would imagine it's the same principle and one thing that comes to mind is, are you absolutely sure that you have included the data folder with the example.txt when you have run the LittleFS formatting tool?

(apologies for the following waffle if you know all this :-)

In PlatformIO you create the data folder, add file(s) to it and then run the tool so that the file(s) are included on the ESP, if you just create the file system with an empty data folder then the no files will exists, that would kinda produce the same result as you are getting, the file system is there but empty. I would imagine it's the same thing on Arduino IDE?

Basically, once you format the system if you later add new files to the data folder they can only be included using the LittleFS tool. A normal code compilation will not also transfer the files to the ESP.

The only ideas I have are:

- either try to redo the LittleFS formatting (with the example.txt in the data folder). Don't know if Linux OS has something to do with the copying of files across?
- try to do something like the following, if the file doesn't exist create it in your code.

  ```
    if(!LittleFS.exists("/example.txt")){
      File file = LittleFS.open("/example.txt", "w+");// w+ should create a file if it doesn't exist
      file.print(""); // may not need to do this
      file.close();
   }else{
      Serial.println("File exists");
   }
  ```

Basically if the file doesn't exists we will try to open it but in the "w+" mode, which should create an empty file and then we close it. I have to admit I haven't tried this approach so it's just an idea.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much! I did overlook the typo indeed. Never thought that this could happen… But as you saïd, this does not solve my problem. Will try your suggestion asap

Comment: Your suggestion did unfortunately not provide a solution. But thanks anyway!

Comment: ah crap...that's annoying...all I can think of is to try using PlatformIO (or the tool directly from Espressif), technically once you've formatted the file system on the ESP you can then use Arduino IDE to work with it. Unless it's some Linux/Arduino IDE issue, don't have a Linux box at the moment to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution:

1. Upload the sketch
2. Close the terminal window (of course the channel is needed by LittleFSuploader)
3. Push the reset button on the nodemcu and use the ESP8266LittleFSDataUpload tool.
4. Push the reset button (again). This seems not always to be necessary.